# Erro ao importar dados .csv para o RStudio

Tags: arquivo, csv, r

Quando vou importar e criar um file meus dados para o R ele da erro...

Tentei o seguinte caminho:

```
 melipona <- paste(system.file(package="dismo"), "/ex/Melipona.csv", sep=";")


 melipona<-read.csv(melipona,header=TRUE,sep=";")
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/N1na3/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dismo/ex/Melipona.csv': No
>   such file or directory

Já tentei usar o `file.choose()` mas ele apenas faz a leitura e não cria o arquivo, então chega uma parte que ele não funciona.
Quando dou o comando `list.files()`g ele aparece o meu arquivo, usei o `getwd()` para ver se estava no mesmo local e está...

Answer (score 4):

O arquivo `Melipona.csv` não está localizado no diretório `C:/Users/N1na3/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dismo/ex/`. Eu listei o conteúdo deste diretório no meu computador e há apenas dois arquivos .csv, chamados `acaule.csv` e `bradypus.csv`.

```
$ ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/dismo/ex/
total 1696
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   191K Apr 21 21:02 acaule.csv
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   487B Apr 21 21:02 bio1.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio1.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   487B Apr 21 21:02 bio12.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio12.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   487B Apr 21 21:02 bio16.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio16.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   487B Apr 21 21:02 bio17.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio17.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   486B Apr 21 21:02 bio5.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio5.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   488B Apr 21 21:02 bio6.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio6.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   486B Apr 21 21:02 bio7.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio7.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   487B Apr 21 21:02 bio8.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    70K Apr 21 21:02 bio8.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   477B Apr 21 21:02 biome.grd
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin    35K Apr 21 21:02 biome.gri
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   4.0K Apr 21 21:02 bradypus.csv
```

Como não tenho acesso ao teu computador, só posso especular uma possível solução para o teu problema. Faça o seguinte:

1) Copie o arquivo `Melipona.csv` para algum lugar conhecido dentro do teu computador. Por exemplo, uma pasta tipo Documentos/Dissertacao/Melipona/Analise/

2) Dentro do RStudio, vá ao menu Session > Set Working Directory > Choose Directory . Navegue até o diretório onde o arquivo `Melipona.csv` está armazenado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Rode o comando

```
melipona <- read.csv("Melipona.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

Isto deve concluir a leitura do teu arquivo sem maiores problemas.

Comment: Confirmado em Windows 7. (A lista de directório acima é unix.) @MarcusNunes Além disso, no comando `read.csv` o nome do ficheiro deve estar entre aspas, edita isso, por favor.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Rui. Publiquei o código sem testar e revisar, por isso este erro apareceu.

Answer (score 0):

Execute novamente o comando:

> melipona <- read.csv(melipona, header=TRUE,sep=";")

Só que dessa vez tente:

```
 melipona <- read.csv('melipona.csv', header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

Tenho esse problema às vezes.